# React useRef to focus on next rendered input field

Tags: reactjs

I want to `focus` on next `input` element added by Add button click

[I have done a demo in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-bhaskara-lkt1h?file=/src/Home.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(ref.current) ref.current.focus();
  },[state])

  // adds new input handler
  const addObject = () => {
    setState([...state, { title: "" }]);
  };
```

The input element:

```
 <input type="text" ref={el => ref.current = el} value={item.title} />
```

State updates are async. So after updating your state its not guaranteed that the line following it will have the updated state.

Comment: Thanks, it was pretty simple afterall

Comment: I also have delete button responsible for deleting each input, now when the component re-renders on delete, it throws error `cannot read property 'focus' of null

Comment: Since the useeffect runs on every state update, this is a likely scenario. However, it will happen only when there is an empty state after deleting. Correct me if am wrong. You can solve this by putting an if statement inside the useeffect and executing it only when your state array count is greater than 0.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my sandbox could you check please

Comment: Updated the answer.